# Python POST to check a box on a webpage

Tags: python, post, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a webpage that posts prices for the Mexico power market. The webpage has checkboxes that need to be checked for the file with prices to show up. Once I get the relevant box checked, I want to pull the links on the page and check if the particular file I am looking for is posted. I am getting stuck in the first part where I get the checkbox selected using requests.post. I used fiddler to track the changes when I post and passed those arguments in through requests.post. 
I was expecting to be able to parse out all the 'href' links in the response but I didn't get any. Any help in redirecting me toward a solution would be greatly appreciated.
Below is the relevant portion of the code I am using:

```
data{
"ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$toolkit":"ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$UpdatePanel1|ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$treePrincipal",
"_EVENTTARGET": "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$treePrincipal",
"__EVENTARGUMENT":{"commandName":"Check","index":"0:0:0:0"},
"__VIEWSTATE": "/verylongstringhere",
"__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR":"6B88769A",
"__EVENTVALIDATION":"/wEdAAPhpIpHlL5kdIfX6MRCtKcRwfFVx5pEsE3np13JV2opXVEvSNmVO1vU+umjph0Dtwe41EcPKcg0qvxOp6m6pWTIV4q0ZOXSBrDwJTrxjo3dZg==",
"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_treePrincipal_ClientState":{"expandedNodes":[],"collapsedNodes":
 [],"logEntries":[],"selectedNodes":[],"checkedNodes":["0","0:0","0:0:0","0:0:0:0"],"scrollPosition":0},
"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ListViewNodos_ClientState":"",
"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_NotifAvisos_ClientState":"",
"ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$NotifAvisos$hiddenState":"",
"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_NotifAvisos_XmlPanel_ClientState":"",
"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_NotifAvisos_TitleMenu_ClientState":"",
"__ASYNCPOST":"true"
}
```

```
headers = {
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Length': '26255',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'Cookie': '_ga=GA1.3.1966843891.1571403663; _gid=GA1.3.1095695800.1571665852',
    'Host': 'www.cenace.gob.mx',
    'Origin': 'https://www.cenace.gob.mx',
    'Referer': 'https://www.cenace.gob.mx/SIM/VISTA/REPORTES/PreEnergiaSisMEM.aspx',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
     Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36',
    'X-MicrosoftAjax': 'Delta=true',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'   
}
```

```
url ="https://www.cenace.gob.mx/SIM/VISTA/REPORTES/PreEnergiaSisMEM.aspx"
r= requests.post(url,data=data, headers=headers, verify=False)
```

This is what Fiddler showed on the Post:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbwLE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have incorrect `__EVENTVALIDATION` or `__VIEWSTATE` fields. You can get the initial page & scrape all the inputs with the initial values.

The following code grabs the input on the first requests, edit them like you did & then send the POST request scraping all the href values :

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = "https://www.cenace.gob.mx"
url = "{}/SIM/VISTA/REPORTES/PreEnergiaSisMEM.aspx".format(base_url)

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
payload = dict([
    (t['name'],t.get('value',''))
    for t in soup.select("input")
    if t.has_attr('name')
])
payload['ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$toolkit'] = 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$UpdatePanel1|ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$treePrincipal'
payload['__EVENTTARGET'] = 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$treePrincipal'
payload['__ASYNCPOST'] = 'true'
payload['__EVENTARGUMENT']= json.dumps({
  "commandName":"Check",
  "index":"0:1:1:0"
})
payload['ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_treePrincipal_ClientState'] = json.dumps({
  "expandedNodes":[], "collapsedNodes":[], 
  "logEntries":[], "selectedNodes":[],
  "checkedNodes":["0","0:1","0:1:1","0:1:1:0"],
  "scrollPosition":0
})

r = requests.post(url, data = payload, headers= {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)"
  })
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

print([ 
  "{}/{}".format(base_url, t["href"]) 
  for t in soup.findAll('a') 
  if not t["href"].startswith('javascript')
])
```